# So I'm trying to understand Exists condition in sql. I know it returns True if there exists one or more tuples

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How does with work. My nested query returns only 3 tuples. But when combined with outer query, it(outer query) returns 736 tuples. And this is the same amount of tuples if I write a query say select p.height from ... where True.

I read the books which says it only returns true which makes sense in my case. Also read few online article where exists returns True but the outer query only selects from the results of nested query.

mysql-workbench

```
select p.height
from world_cup.player as p
where Exists(select q.height from world_cup.player as q where q.height = 165)
order by p.height;
```

Actual result should have been those three tuples 165, 165, 165(according to the book and online resources)

Comment: To understand your question correctly, when you say _"And this is the same amount of tuples if I write a query say select p.height from ... where True"_ , does that mean when you do a simple `SELECT * FROM world_cup.player AS p WHERE  p.height=165;`, does it return 3 or 736? Kinda confuse with the _same amount_ claim because you mentioned two values

Comment: ya the query you wrote results 3 tuples only. And say if I write the query from the question and a query say    select p.height
from world_cup.player as p
where  True;    Both of these result the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I got to test myself and what you said is correct. However from the link you're referring to here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp , you're missing one condition whereby you need to have a `p.height=q.height`before `q.height=165` for it to return the values correctly. Hence, your query suppose to be like this:

```
SELECT p.height
FROM world_cup.player AS p
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT q.height FROM world_cup.player AS q 
               WHERE p.height=q.height -- you're missing this condition
                 AND q.height = 165
              )
ORDER BY p.height;
```

Here's a reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

*"For the preceding example, if t2 contains any rows, even rows with nothing but NULL values, the EXISTS condition is TRUE."*

Comment: awesomeeeee thank you so much, this thing was bugging me so much.

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` is true if and only if the subquery returns at least one tuple.

So as long there's at least one player with a height of 165, your `EXISTS` returns true, for **all** tuples of the outer query that is. If there were no such player you had an empty set as result. So you see your use is pretty static and maybe doesn't make too much sense used in that way, unless that is what you intended.

Usually the subquery to an `EXISTS` is correlated, i.e. a value of the outer query appears in the `WHERE` clause of the inner query, so that the results of `EXISTS` can differ from tuple to tuple of the outer query.

If you just want player with a height of 165 simply use the equality expression in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT p.height
       FROM world_cup.player as p
       WHERE p.height = 165;
```

The `ORDER BY p.height` is useless then too as they're all the same.

Comment: I understand that. But my question is why is it returning all the existing tuples and not just those 3 tuples?

Comment: @NameetNameet: It rather seems like you didn't understand. Read my post again: "So as long there's at least one player with a height of 165, your `EXISTS` returns true ...". And you said there are three players with such a height, so even more than one.

Comment: I know that. WHAT I AM SAYING IS WHY IS IT RETURNING ALL THE TUPLES AND NOT JUST THOSE 3 TUPLES. Cause from what I have read is that it selects from the inner query. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp

Comment: Or just tell me how do I use exists here, I created this question to understand that condition.

Comment: @NameetNameet: No need to SHOUT, that won't help you get it. Again, read my answer carefully, I explained to you why it behaves as it does. And your link doesn't claim to only select the tuples of the inner query in the outer query. But it shows you the correlation I mentioned. And I already told you, `EXISTS` is not the right way here to get the players with that height.

Comment: so you are saying, from that link query 1 - SELECT SupplierName
FROM Suppliers
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ProductName FROM Products WHERE Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.supplierID AND Price < 20);

query 2 - SELECT SupplierName
FROM Suppliers
WHERE True;

would both result the same?
I wasn't shouting I was reminding coz I have written it in the title that I understand how Exists work for this case, but what I can't understand is why is it showing different results in this case. 
Also, I know this is not the way to fetch heights n all I just made up this question to understand EXISTS.